# ExpandString breaks EOL

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation, eol, variable-expansion

### Context

I have a multi line file named `DEV.properties`. It contains references to ENV variables

```
ACTIVEMQ_DB_USERNAME=${ACTIVEMQ_DB_USERNAME}
```

I am writing a ps script to replace this file with one populated with the relevant variables

### Problem

Here is how I proceed

```bsh
#first load variables from a file
Get-Content C:\somewhere\over\the\rainbow\.credentials | Foreach-Object{$var = $_.Split('=');New-Variable -Name $var[0] -Value $var[1]}
$template = Get-Content DEV.properties
$expanded = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
```

Substitution is successful but while `$template` is a multi line string, all **CRLF** seems to have disappeared from `$expanded`. How can I fix it? Is there a more direct approach than looping though all lines?

Comment: `Get-Content` returns a string array (one string per line). Use `$template = Get-Content DEV.properties -Raw` instead to read the whole template as a single multi-line string

Answer (score 2):

```
$expanded = $template | %{ $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_) }
```